# How can I check out books and search books in a Library project in Java?

Tags: java

I am working on a Library system project for my Java programming class. I need to be able to search through the list of books in the Book array by author or title. In addition, I would also like to see how to check out books in the system. I would appreciate any help or insight. The searchBooks and checkoutBook methods are at the bottom. Thanks again!

Sincerely,
Moon

```
package Project;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Library {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Book> booklist = new ArrayList<Book>();
ArrayList<Users> user = new ArrayList<Users>();
static int running = 0;
String booksearch;
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    (new Library()).run();
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            System.out.println("********************Welcome to the Public Library!********************");
            System.out.println("              Please Select From The Following Options:               ");
            System.out.println("**********************************************************************");


            System.out.println("1: Create a new account");
            System.out.println("2: Admin login");
            System.out.println("3: User login");
            System.out.println("0: Exit");  
            int option = input.nextInt();
            switch (option) {
            case 1: newAccount();  break;
            case 2: admin(); break;
            case 3: userLogin();   break;
            case 0: System.exit(option); break;
            case 5: return;
            default: System.out.println("Wrong option, try again.");

        }


    }

}
    public void addBook(){
        Book book1 = new Book("Game of Thrones","Fantasy","George RR Martin","a book about dragons",9001,5);
        Book book2 = new Book("Harry Potter","Adventure","JK Rowling","a boy goes to a magical school",23454,3);
        Book book3 = new Book("Carrie","Horror","Stephen King","a girl goes crazy",3332,15);
        Book book4 = new Book("Dragonaball","Action Manga","Akira Toriyama","a boy with power fights evil",27894,2);
        booklist.add(book1);
        booklist.add(book2);
        booklist.add(book3);
        booklist.add(book4);

    }

    private void userLogin() {


                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter your username ");
                String user = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter your password ");
                String pass = keyboard.nextLine(); // looks at selected file in scan


                if (user.equals("olumide1") && pass.equals("umbc")) {
                    System.out.println("********************Welcome Home, User!********************");
                    System.out.println("              Please Select From The Following Options:               ");
                    System.out.println("**********************************************************************");
                    System.out.println("1: checkout a book:");
                    System.out.println("2: search a book:");
                    System.out.println("3: exit library:");
                    int option = input.nextInt();
                    switch(option){
                    case 1: checkOutBook(); break;
                    case 2: searchBooks(); break;
                    case 3: System.exit(0);
                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.print("Try again");
                }
            }

    public void searchBooks() {
        System.out.println("Which book are you searching for today?");
        booksearch = input.nextLine();

         }

    private void checkOutBook() {
    }
```

Comment: Javascript != Java. Please don't spam tags.

Comment: Well, for `searchBooks` you would get the information from the user, and then iterate over the 'booklist` and find the books that matched. I'm guessing the `Book` class has a `.getTitle()` that might be used. As it stands, you've provided too little information (missing `Book` class) and too little effort (haven't even attempted implementing the methods).

Answer (score 0):

To search a Book, simply iterate through your `bookList` and search by title or author. Also, I suggest that your `searchBooks()` method should return a `Book` instance:

```
public Book searchBooks() {
    System.out.println("Which book are you searching for today?");
    booksearch = input.nextLine();
    for (Book book : booklist)
    {
        if (book.getTitle().contains(booksearch) || book.getAuthor().contains(booksearch)
        {
             return book; 
        }
    }
    return null; //no book was found
```

}

To track checked out / free books, simply create a new `List` of books that are checked out `checkedOutBooks`. You `checkOutBook` method should accept `Book` argument:

```
private void checkOutBook(Book book) {
    checkedOutBooks.add(book);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for search book method you can use hashmap, google and spend some time on it. Please provide detail for checkoutbook, what needs to be done in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 Pojo's

```
     Class Book
    {
    int id;
    int quantity;
     String bookName;
    Author author;
    } 

    Class Author
    {
    int authorId;
    String authorName;
    List<Integer>bookIdsList;
    }
```

Intialize the class with 3 Maps

```
        TreeMap<String,Integer>bookSearchMap  //String is the bookName // Integer is the book Id  
        TreeMap<String,Author>authorSearchMap //String is the authorName
        HashMap<Integer,Book>bookData  // for checking out the book with the Id of book
```

so the 2 TreeMap will help you in searching 
and HashMap will help you in checking out . 
If you want a prefix search you can use TRIE structure but that you will have to implement .